# Accessing image resources from a loaded assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, resources, .net-assembly

I have a simple plugin architecture for my program that uses an interface to return an ImageSource for an icon. I want each plugin to be able to add an icon/image resource to the assembly and return it from its implemented class.

The problem I'm running into is that when I use my previous trick, which was to instantiate an ImageSourceConverter and pass it a pack uri, doesn't work with loaded assemblies because the converter loads the resource from the main assembly.

```
public static ImageSource FromResourcePath( string path ) {
    return (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom( "pack://application:,,,/" + path.TrimStart( '/' ) );
}
```

Is there any (hopefully straightforward) way to get an ImageSource from an assembly resource (stored as a WPF "Resource" content type) from a loaded assembly? I'd like to avoid using streams if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"pack://application:,,,/<PutHereAssemblyName>;component/" + path.TrimStart('/')
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Super, thanks! I just used Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name for the name and it works. :)